# input value in python thread while printing text received

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to developp a multiplayer maze game in Python.
There is a server handling the game communicating with several clients.
I am having trouble with the client, that needs to be able to simultaneously:

- print messages he receives from the server,
- input commands to send to the server

I am trying to do this using Threads; however if the server sends several messages in a raw, my client will need to input something before printing the second message.

Is there a way that the client can print messages whenever he receives them, and send one only when the user enters something ?

Here is my code:

```
import socket
from threading import Thread


connection_with_server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
connection_with_server.connect(('localhost',12800))
print('connected to the server')

def receive_and_print():
    """ print message received from server """
    msg_recvd = connection_with_server.recv(1024)
    if (msg_recvd!=b''):
        print('The server says: \n'+msg_recvd.decode())

def enter_and_send():
    """ input a message and send it to server """
    msg_to_send = input('> ')
    if (msg_to_send != ''):
        msg_to_send = msg_to_send.encode()
        connection_with_server.send(msg_to_send)
        print('\n message sent')
    return msg_to_send

msg_to_send = b""
while msg_to_send != b"end":
    reception = Thread(target=receive_and_print)
    reception.start()
    msg_to_send=enter_and_send()
    reception.join()

print('closing connection')
connection_with_server.close()
```

Here is an example output I would like, for instance if the server sends two messages then the client sends one and then the server again:

```
connected to the server
>
The server says:
message 1 from server
>
The server says:
message 2 from server
> message entered by user
message sent
>
The server says:
message 3 from server
>
```

I've been struggling with that issue for a few days now, any suggestion is more than welcome !
Thank you !

EDIT : It looks I managed to solve the problem by running the code of receive_and_print in a while True loop and imposing a timeout=0 for joining the reception thread.

Comment: It's not totally clear what you want here. If the client sits there not typing anything, and the server sends 5 messages to the client, what is the expected/desired behaviour?

Comment: In the main question, you say: "if the server sends several messages in a raw, my client will need to input something before printing the second message." In the example output, it appears the server sends 2 messages to the client, which are both displayed without the client sending anything back. I'm confused.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tom. The example output is what I want to have in the end. But with my current code which I put, it is not that way, and the client has to input something every time before it can print a received message again. In fact it looks like the received messages are stocked and executed only once the line reception.join() is read which does not happen before enter_and_send() is executed